# Automatically rename folder based on tags of contents

Tags: windows, automation

Right now I have a folder that has all my music. Inside I have sub folders with the correct name (artist name). However, inside of these folders, the names are not correct (I want them to be the name of the album it contains. All my mp3 files are properly tagged, and in every folder there is only one album. Is there anyway to get the album name and rename the parent folder to this (without doing it manually!).

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there are a ton of applications that can do this but I personally use [MusicBrainz Picard](http://musicbrainz.org/). You can set it to move the files to a new directory and load them up in the program then cluster them and use **Lookup** if you use scan it will fingerprint the song and not use existing metadata to identify them. After the albums are all identified correctly you can save them and it will move them to the directory structure you want by default... you can alter it under the options.